# URL redirection using javascript in an MVC3 application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, url, redirect

```
   @{
        var host = Url.Content("~/");
    } 


<script type="text/javascript">
    var host = "@host";
    $(function () {

        if ($("#Company" != null)) {
            $("#companyselect").change(function () {

                var newuri = host + "eg/" + $("#companyselect option:selected").text() + "/Comps";
                window.location.url = newuri;
            }
            );
        }
    });
</script>
```

**newuri = /bo/eg/airline inc/5**

But browser always redirects to **/eg/airline inc/5**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you are missing the hostname? In your current setup it looks like the hostname would evaluate to simply "/";

For example you could try:

```
var host = window.location.hostname;
var newuri = host + "/eg/" + $("#companyselect option:selected").text() + "/Comps";
window.location.url = newuri;
```

Comment: Nah. It was even dumber than that. I had a $(function) definition that had gotten hidden within a partial the page was loading. The net result was it was overwriting the newuri with the legacy path.